# Regex match strings only after certain character

Tags: regex, sublimetext

I want to remove all numbers, but only after `|`

```
blah, 1. retain 3. dont alter..blah | blah 1. remove balh.. 19. altered
```

after I apply regex the string should be

```
blah, 1. retain 3. dont alter..blah | blah remove balh..  altered
```

when I replace using this regex `[0-9]+\.` It matches all the "numbers with dot" even before `|` , and when I use regex `| [0-9]+\.` it only selects the first number and dot i.e `1.`, after |

Comment: Just convert matches of the following regular expression to empty strings:`\d+\.(?!.*\|)`. [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/gXhlQe/1). `(?!.*\|)` is a *negative lookahead*, asserting that the match cannot be followed later in the string by a pipe character.

Comment: @CarySwoveland thanks, it worked! an excellent idea!  if you like, please post it as an answer so that I can accept it and others can get benefit from it, thank you so much for your help:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can assert not a pipe char to the right using a negative lookahead and using a [negated character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated) ruling out a newline or `|`:

```
\d+\.(?![^\r\n|]*\|)
```

**Explanation**

- `\d+\.` Match 1+ digits and a dot
- `(?!` Negative lookahead, assert not to the right

  - `[^\r\n|]*\|` Match optional chars other than a newline or `|`
- `)` Close lookahead

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/QbjPYV/1).

---

Another option is to use a positive lookahead to assert not a pipe char to the right until the end of the string:

```
\d+\.(?=[^\r\n|]*$)
```

**Explanation**

- `\d+\.` Match 1+ digits and a dot
- `(?=` Positive lookahead, assert to the right

  - `[^\r\n|]*$` Match optional chars other than a newline or `|` till end of string `$`
- `)` Close lookahead

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/H7ZPk0/1).